# Do we need to begin transaction before making any changes in persistent objects?

Tags: java, hibernate

Can I use transaction like below:

```
persistentObj.setValue("xyz");
session.beginTransaction().commit();
```

assuming session is created before fetching object from database?

Answer (score 1):

As you write above, only the object is changed. It will not be persisted to the database.

You must call `persist()` or `saveOrUpdate()` method to make changes to object. You should also follow this order: begin transaction, update or save, and then commit.

Comment: If object is fetched in the same session, then it will be in persistent state. Is it right? If yes, Do I need to call saveOrUpdate()? or I can call commit() without calling saveOrUpdate().

Comment: In that case, I think you should call flush instead of beginning a new transaction and commit

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking same.

Comment: @Tuleism No, if it is managed object, then the changes made will be reflected in the database when the transaction commits, flush implicitly. But to control the object persistence manually, methods must be used rather than depending on container. Can refer similar post http://stackoverflow.com/q/8071673/366964 for further information.