# Avoid having JPA to automatically persist objects

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Is there any way to avoid having JPA to automatically persist objects?

I need to use a third party API and I have to pull/push from data from/to it. I've got a class responsible to interface the API and I have a method like this:

```
public User pullUser(int userId) {
    Map<String,String> userData = getUserDataFromApi(userId);
    return new UserJpa(userId, userData.get("name"));
}
```

Where the `UserJpa` class looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class UserJpa implements User
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String name;

    public UserJpa() {
    }

    public UserJpa(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When I call the method (e.g. `pullUser(1)`), the returned user is automatically stored in the database. I don't want this to happen, is there a solution to avoid it? I know a solution could be to create a new class implementing `User` and return an instance of this class in the `pullUser()` method, is this a good practice?

Thank you.

Comment: JPA doesn't persist new objects automatically. Perhaps you persist that object somewhere in your code, or associate it with persistent object via relationship with cascaded persist.

Comment: There's something more going on somewhere in your code, JPA is pretty cool, but it is not so magic as to automatically save objects just because you created them with a constructor.

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8083084/366964

Comment: Thank you @axtavt, you were right, it was a cascaded persist. Problem solved! (if you post your solution as an answer I will accept it)

Comment: (and thank you @Affe, if it was that magic to automatically save objects when calling the constructor, it wouldn't be that cool =])

Comment: @satoshi: I think answer of Mikko Maunu is good enough, don't see the sense in posting duplicate answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Newly create instance of UserJpa is not persisted in pullUser. I assume also that there is not some odd implementation in getUserDataFromApi actually persisting something for same id.

In your case entity manager knows nothing about new instance of UserJPA. Generally entities are persisted via merge/persist calls or as a result of cascaded merge/persist operation. Check for these elsewhere in code base.

Answer (score 0):

The only way in which a new entity gets persisted in JPA is by explicitly calling the `EntityManager`'s `persist()` or `merge()` methods. Look in your code for calls to either one of them, that's the point where the persist operation is occurring, and refactor the code to perform the persistence elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Generally JPA Objects are managed objects, these objects reflect their changes into the database when the transaction completes and before on a first level cache, obviously these objects need to become managed on the first place.

I really think that a best practice is to use a DTO object to handle the data transfering and then use the entity just for persistence purposes, that way it would be more cohesive and lower coupling, this is no objects with their nose where it shouldnt.

Hope it helps.