# Avoiding entity update directly on form submit

Tags: jpa, seam

I have an entity which is showed on the screen as text in input boxes which can be modified. When i submit the form hitting save, i would like my ejb3 component to handle the data and persist or merge it using the entity manager. But for some reason, when i modify the data and hit save the data directly gets updated in the database by-pasing my ejb3, which is certainly undesirable. My code looks like the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMP")
public class Emp implements java.io.Serializable {

private short empno;
private Dept dept;
private String ename;
private String job;
private Short mgr;
private Date hiredate;
private BigDecimal sal;
private BigDecimal comm;

public Emp() {
}

public Emp(short empno) {
    this.empno = empno;
}
public Emp(short empno, Dept dept, String ename, String job, Short mgr,
        Date hiredate, BigDecimal sal, BigDecimal comm) {
    this.empno = empno;
    this.dept = dept;
    this.ename = ename;
    this.job = job;
    this.mgr = mgr;
    this.hiredate = hiredate;
    this.sal = sal;
    this.comm = comm;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "EMPNO", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 4, scale = 0)
public short getEmpno() {
    return this.empno;
}

public void setEmpno(short empno) {
    this.empno = empno;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPTNO")
public Dept getDept() {
    return this.dept;
}

public void setDept(Dept dept) {
    this.dept = dept;
}

@Column(name = "ENAME", length = 10)
@Length(max = 10)
public String getEname() {
    return this.ename;
}

public void setEname(String ename) {
    this.ename = ename;
}

@Column(name = "JOB", length = 9)
@Length(max = 9)
public String getJob() {
    return this.job;
}

public void setJob(String job) {
    this.job = job;
}

@Column(name = "MGR", precision = 4, scale = 0)
public Short getMgr() {
    return this.mgr;
}

public void setMgr(Short mgr) {
    this.mgr = mgr;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "HIREDATE", length = 7)
public Date getHiredate() {
    return this.hiredate;
}

public void setHiredate(Date hiredate) {
    this.hiredate = hiredate;
}

@Column(name = "SAL", precision = 7)
public BigDecimal getSal() {
    return this.sal;
}

public void setSal(BigDecimal sal) {
    this.sal = sal;
}

@Column(name = "COMM", precision = 7)
public BigDecimal getComm() {
    return this.comm;
}

public void setComm(BigDecimal comm) {
    this.comm = comm;
}
```

}

```
    @Stateful
    @Name("workflow")
    @Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
    public class WorkflowBean implements Workflow
    {
    @Logger private Log log;

    @In StatusMessages statusMessages;


    @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    EntityManager entityManager;


    @Out(required=false)
    Emp employee = new Emp();

    @RequestParameter("empEmpno")
    String empNo;


    public void workflow()
    {

        log.info("workflow.workflow() action called");
        statusMessages.add("workflow");

    } 
    @End
    public boolean save(){
       entityManager.merge(emp);
       entityManger.flush();
    }
    @Begin(join=true)
    public boolean populateEmp(){
        entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
        System.out.println("The Emp No. is---"+empNo);
        int no = Integer.parseInt(empNo);
        short emp =(short)no;
        employee = entityManager.find(Emp.class, emp);
        entityManager.flush();
        return true;
    }
    public Emp getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Emp employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
    // add additional action methods

    public String getEmpNo() {
        return empNo;
    }

    public void setEmpNo(String empNo) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
    }
    @Remove
    @Destroy
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

My view looks like

```
<h:form id="emp" styleClass="edit">

        <rich:panel>
            <f:facet name="header">Edit Emp</f:facet>

            <s:decorate id="empnoField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Empno</ui:define>
                <h:inputText id="empno"
                       required="true"
                          value="#{workflow.employee.empno}">
                </h:inputText>
            </s:decorate>


            <s:decorate id="commField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Comm</ui:define>
                <h:inputText id="comm"
                          value="#{workflow.employee.comm}"
                           size="14">
                </h:inputText>
            </s:decorate>



            <s:decorate id="enameField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Ename</ui:define>
                <h:inputText id="ename"
                           size="10"
                      maxlength="10"
                          value="#{workflow.employee.ename}">
                </h:inputText>
            </s:decorate>


            <s:decorate id="hiredateField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Hiredate</ui:define>
                <rich:calendar id="hiredate"
                          value="#{workflow.employee.hiredate}" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
            </s:decorate>


            <s:decorate id="jobField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Job</ui:define>
                <h:inputText id="job"
                           size="9"
                      maxlength="9"
                          value="#{workflow.employee.job}">
                </h:inputText>
            </s:decorate>


            <s:decorate id="mgrField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Mgr</ui:define>
                <h:inputText id="mgr"
                          value="#{workflow.employee.mgr}">
                </h:inputText>
            </s:decorate>


            <s:decorate id="salField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Sal</ui:define>
                <h:inputText id="sal"
                          value="#{workflow.employee.sal}"
                           size="14">
                </h:inputText>
            </s:decorate>
            <s:decorate id="deptField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
                <ui:define name="label">Department</ui:define>
                <h:inputText id="dname"
                          value="#{workflow.deptName}">
                </h:inputText>
            </s:decorate>
            <div style="clear:both">
                <span class="required">*</span>
                required fields
            </div>

        </rich:panel>

        <div class="actionButtons">

            <h:commandButton id="save"
                          value="Save"
                         action="#{workflow.save}"
                       rendered="true"/>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: do you want to insert a new record instead of updated in database.?

Comment: Similar one, can refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8083084/366964

Comment: @Nayan:I had to use a transient field in the entity for this as I cannot play with the Auto-Commit part. But then it raises the same old situation where I have to set the transient values first before rendering the view, which deviates from the whole logic of having seam to take care of this part.

Answer (score 0):

*[It was difficult to address issue in comments for your response.]*

There are few things which I haven't understand & why it's done that way.

- Using transient fields, it will add overhead of adding those to entity object while persisting.
- Why is auto-commit causes issue & can't be implemented.

Regardless of these things, you can try

- Making the entity detached with `entityManager.detach(entity)` or clearing the persistence context with `entityManager.clear()`, detaching all the underlying entities. But prior one is more favourible.
- Can manage transaction manually instead of container. Use BMT where you can have control over the operations.